# Updating Shipping price via Amazon API

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

Is there a way to update shipping price for an existing product in amazon via Amazon API. I checked the API documentation for Feeds API, Product's API but can't find any. There is a way by uploading CSV file but I was wondering if there is a way using API.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would update shipping through the Overrides Feed.  The .xsd fields seem to support this, although I have not used this particular part of the API.

[FeedType API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html)

[Article Describing API Features including Shipping Override capability in Feeds API](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=188469)